# Eclipse android device chooser doesn't show my phone

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin, device

I'm using the android plugin for eclipse and when i try to run my program using adb but my device is not listed. 
I check usb debugging mode. I clean cache, but not solved.

(usign windows 8/My phones Htc one x (4.1.1) and samsung s3 (4.1.1).)

Comment: Is your USB cord connected? Does Windows see your phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed [HTC Sync Manager](http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/) then it works.

Comment: Also, do not forget to unlock Your Developer Options on HTC Device, if it is above 4.2 then go to Settings->About->Software information->More->Build number and click on it 7 times.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to enable the developpement  USB debugging

On your phone, go to Settings->app settings->developing->enable first option

Answer (score 0):

Did you [download](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) the USB driver for your device?

[Specifically](http://samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535MBBVZW) for Samsung S III.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line, type `adb devices` in your `SDK_FOLDER/platform-tools` folder.

If your device is detected, then run eclipse as admin.
If your device is not detected, then try update the drivers (found in `SDK_FOLDER/extras/google/usb_driver`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your application over an android device like HTC then first of all you have to download and then install HTC synchronization Manager form here [HTC Synchronization Manager](http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/).
After that follow the below pictures steps.

[image]
   [image]